# I have member that is a pointer to a parameterized function, can I extend a parameter type?

Tags: c++, lambda, function-pointers

Constructor takes and sets a member that has the type:

```
void (*callBackFunc)(void *context, VideoSprite *pCaller)
```

Now I need to extend this to include more data than `VideoSprite` holds. I will `static_cast` in the `static` callback like this:

```
static void staticFuncToInitRot(void *context, VideoSprite *pCaller)
{
    spinningSprite *winSpin = static_cast<spinningSprite*>(pCaller);
```

Is this okay? No risk of slicing or anything hard to detect? Also can you tell me which c'tor will be called and why?

```
    DelayedCallback(void *context, VideoSprite *pCaller, std::function<void(void *context, VideoSprite *pCaller)> lambda) :
        lambda(lambda),
        callBackFunc(NULL),
        context(context),
        pCaller(pCaller),
    {}
    DelayedCallback(void *context, VideoSprite *pCaller, void (*callBackFunc)(void *context, VideoSprite *pCaller)) :
        callBackFunc(callBackFunc),
        context(context),
        pCaller(pCaller),
    {}
```

Only one alternative member is `NULL`ified because the callback executes with:

```
            if (callBackFunc) callBackFunc(context, pCaller);
            else lambda(context, pCaller);
```

I can't remember if I needed the `lambda` or left it there for perceived future proofing benefits.

The c'tor is called like this from `VideoSprite` (`context` is `nullptr`)

```
actionList.push_back(new DelayedCallback(context, this, callBackFunc));
```

where `callBackFunc` is a pointer to

```
static void staticFuncToInitRot(void *context, VideoSprite *pCaller)
```

I really don't need a `dynamic_cast` thanks and I appreciate your concern.

Comment: You haven't shown any code that would initialize a `DelayedCallback`, so we can't say which ctor is called.

Comment: @aschepler no, sorry for assuming youd take a stab in the dark at using `staticFuncToInitRot` which I've just made explicit.

Answer (score 1):

```
static void staticFuncToInitRot(void *context, VideoSprite *pCaller)
{
    spinningSprite *winSpin = static_cast<spinningSprite*>(pCaller);
```

> Is this okay? No risk of slicing or anything hard to detect? Also can you tell me which c'tor will be called and why?

It will be better to do a `dynamic_cast` to make sure that you are not accidentally casting another sub-type of `VideoSprite` to `spinningSprite` and assuming it is a valid cast.

```
static void staticFuncToInitRot(void *context, VideoSprite *pCaller)
{
    spinningSprite *winSpin = dynamic_cast<spinningSprite*>(pCaller);
    if ( winSpin )
    {
       // Safe to use the pointer
    }
}
```

As to which constructor will be called...

When you use:

```
actionList.push_back(new DelayedCallback(context, this, callBackFunc));
```

the second constructor will be called. I don't know why you feel it's ambiguous. The second constructor takes an argument whose type is a direct match of the argument being used.

You can force the first constructor to be used by using

```
actionList.push_back(new DelayedCallback(context, this, std::function<void(void *, VideoSprite *)>(callBackFunc)));
```

Comment: I take a break from C++ while C++11 gets rolled out with lambda's and I'm being molly coddled already! What about slicing and `static_cast` I'm still safe with that right? And don't I have an ambiguous overload?

Comment: @John, do you have something against the use of `dynamic_cast`? I don't understand why use of a safer alternative to `static_cast` is molly coddling the language.

Comment: It's very much slower though isn't it? Granted 100 ms is neither here nor there, but in a UI it is noticable. Plus I don't think Android has full RTTI, at least not that is widely used.

Comment: It is slower than `static_cast` and should be avoided in performance critical pieces but is not so bad that its use needs to be shunned. In your case, you can take the risk of using `static_cast` iff you are *very sure* that the function won't get called for any other sub-type of `VideoSprite` AND the function gets called a lot of times.

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind answering why I feel I have ambiguously overloaded my constructor?

Comment: @John, I updated answer. Hopefully that answers your second question.